# How to make sidebar visible by default?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code the sidebar is collapsed by default. I want to have the file list always visible.

Is there a setting for this?

Answer (score 1):

When you open VS Code on a single file or via `File | New Window` the side bar is collapsed to focus on the editor area. As soon as you open a folder, the side bar will reveal the contents of the folder.

Currently there is no way to always show the side bar when opening a single file. To open the side bar, use the `Ctrl+B` (Mac: `Cmd+B`) key binding.

Comment: 8 years later there still no setting for this????

Answer (score 0):

I don't have this behavior. If you exit VSCODE, VSCODE will save the visible state of the sidebar. Next time you open VSCODE, VSCODE will restore the saved visible state.

Comment: In my case VSCode only restores visible sidebar if I opened a folder before I close the app. If I open only a single file the sidebar is hidden (which is ok if I only edit one file, but if I open another file the sidebar is still hidden).